# Custom url to hide specific url/domain

Tags: php, url

Basically I have a website which is set up with a specific domain, I want users to access this website but through a custom url without ever being able to find out the true domain name. Is this possible?

I would like the custom url to expire after a set amount of time as well. I will be using PHP.

Comment: It's possible but only with great pain, and second domain, and a server that you can custom configure to run a reverse proxy. Note that a header redirect (which may come up as a proposed solution) does *not* reliably hide the original domain name.

Comment: If you are in for DDOS protection, look into CloudFlare.